# Is there any way to get the number of pending chat request on omni channel?

Tags: lightning, liveagent, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, omnichannel

I have a requirement to get the number of pending chat request in the omni channel.

I have set the presence configuration capacity to 5 so that an agent can have only 5 chat requests. if a case is solved agent will get one of the pending chat request. But right now i can't see the number of pending request.

[image]

Lets say i have 10 pending request in the queue, but i don't have any numbers to see how many are pending in the queue.

Is there any way that can show the pending chat requests in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple query,

```
SELECT Id, WorkItemId
FROM PendingServiceRouting
WHERE IsPushed = FALSE
AND IsReadyForRouting = TRUE
```

This means PSR(PendingServiceRouting) is ready to be routed and Yet to be pushed to anyone's queue.

You can make a custom lightning components that shows the count.